# I have a problem with multiple Security Groups in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I am trying to select two Security Groups, one is from parameters and other is a new one.

But getting below errors. How can I solve this?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : 2010-09-09
Description: "simple web layer"
Parameters:
  ImageId:
    Description: 'web Layer'
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
    Default: ami-244333
  Vpc:
    Description: enter vpc
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::VPC::Id>  
  Securitycab:
    Type: String
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    Description: enter vpc ip range    
  Subnets:
    Description: enter subnet
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
    Default: subnet-384736383838
  Securitygroup:
    Description: enter sc
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>
    Default: sg-237377383773873
Resources:
  Lpsecurity:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
          VpcId: vpc-1a2b3c4d
          GroupDescription: Sample target security group
          SecurityGroupIngress:        
          - IpProtocol: tcp
            FromPort: 80
            ToPort: 80
            CidrIp: !Ref Securitycab
  MyEC2Instance1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref ImageId
      InstanceType: t2.large
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      SubnetId: !Select [ 0, !Ref Subnets ]
      SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref Securitygroup
            !Ref Lpsecurity
```

> Error : Unsolved Resource dependence [Securitygroup !Ref Lpsecurity] in the resource block of the template.

Comment: I think you have too many spaces in the `Lpsecurity` properties section.

Answer (score 1):

A list should have **dashes before every element**.

Here is the suggested code from your other [I have a problem in cloud formation. Error when using Fn::Join with a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60136431/174777) question:

```
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt Securitygroup.GroupId
        - !GetAtt Lpsecurity.GroupId
```

Alternatively, you could possibly use:

```
      SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref Securitygroup
          - !Ref Lpsecurity
```