# I have a problem in cloud formation. Error when using Fn::Join with a parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I am trying to create one Security Group and calling other security group from parameters using cloudformation. I used this as a resource however I get the following error message from cloudfromation

> Template validation error: Template error: every Fn::Join object
>   requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of
>   strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings
>   (such as Fn::GetAZs) to be joined.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : 2010-09-09
Description: "simple web layer"
Parameters:
Securitygroupid:
Description: enter sc
Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>
NoEcho: false
Default: sg-05323df39f12d8034

Resources:
   Lpsecurity:
Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
Properties:
Securitygroupid:
Description: enter sc
Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
NoEcho: false
Default: sg-05323df39f12d8034
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      GroupDescription: Sample target security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:        
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        CidrIp: !Ref Securitycab
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 443
        ToPort: 443
        CidrIp: !Ref Securitycab 
   MyEC2Instance1:
     Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
     Properties:
       ImageId: !Ref ImageId
       InstanceType: t2.micro
       SubnetId: !Select [ 0, !Ref Subnets ]
       SecurityGroupIds: !Join [ ",", [ !Ref Securitygroupid, !Ref Lpsecurity ]]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try removing `!Join`, so it is just: `SecurityGroupIds: [ !Ref Securitygroup, !Ref Lpsecurity ]`.

Comment: If i remove !Join my stack is getting failed with Error: Value of property SecurityGroupIds must be of type List of String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution.

```
SecurityGroupIds:  !Split
    - ","
    - !Sub
      - "${idList},${Lpsecurity}"
      - idList: !Join [",",!Ref "SecurityGroup"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [SecurityGroupIds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-securitygroupids) should be a list type.

Try the following

```
Resources:
  Lpsecurity:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      GroupDescription: Sample target security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: !Ref Securitycab
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          CidrIp: !Ref Securitycab
  MyEC2Instance1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref ImageId
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SubnetId: !Select [ 0, !Ref Subnets ]
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref Securitygroup
        - !GetAtt Lpsecurity.GroupId
```

Comment: If i add above code now iam getting Error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource Securitygroup

Comment: @RavikiranAlapati Good, that's getting closer! Could you please update your Question to show where `Securitygroup` is defined?

Comment: @John Rotenstein Updated the code, In Parameters User will select multiple  Security Group.

Comment: Oh, that's different to what you originally asked. (It's always best to show the code!) So you are adding an element to an existing list. That will take some playing around. Try some of these ideas: [How to append a list in CloudFormation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46856867/174777)

Comment: @John Rotenstein Iam getting same error after adding below code.  SecurityGroupIds: !Join [ ",", [ !Join [ ",", [ !Ref SecurityGroup ] ], !Ref Lpsecurity ] ], How can i include both Securitygroup and Lpsecurity in SecurityGroupIds

Comment: Yes, you'll need to play around to figure out how to add an element to an existing list. `!Join` normally joins strings, I'm not sure how to use it to append to an existing list. Hopefully somebody will be able to assist.

Comment: I found solution.
SecurityGroupIds:  !Split
        - ","
        - !Sub
          - "${idList},${Lpsecurity}"
          - idList: !Join [",",!Ref "SecurityGroup"]